# Каст Object[] в CharSequnce[]

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Доброго времени суток. Есть код ниже:

```
categories = pushPostPresenter.getCategories();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        final CharSequence[] categoriesCharSequence = (CharSequence[]) categories.toArray();
        builder.setTitle(R.string.push_choose_category)
                .setItems(categoriesCharSequence, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        category = categoriesCharSequence[which].toString();
                    }
                });
        builder.create();
```

Суть в том, что метод **.setItems()** принимает на вход массив *CharSequence[]*. А переменная categories у меня типа *ArrayList< String>*. Собственно, мне пишет:

*java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence[]*

Хотя, по-сути, **toArray()** возвращает массив объектов, почему мы не можем скастовать их в *CharSequence[]* ?

Как решить такую проблему? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что Java не позволяет приводить `Object[]` к массиву более частного типа.

Воспользуйтесь методом `toArray(T[] a)` вместо `toArray()`, который вернёт массив нужного типа, как это сделано [вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5061692/3100967)

Comment: Да ладно? http://ideone.com/KRfTpx

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6 *From any array type SC[] to any array type TC[], provided that SC and TC are reference types and there is a narrowing reference conversion from SC to TC.* т.е. если я не ошибаюсь, Object[] можно скастовать во что угодно, пока известен T (я имею в виду момент с дженериками). Что довольно странно в разрезе ошибки у ТС.

Comment: @etki, а воспроизводится: http://ideone.com/IeDBPf

Comment: @Qwertiy да, я только не понимаю, что я неправильно выцепил в jls

Comment: @etki, напиши, пожалуйста подробный ответ. Я тогда свой удалю. Оба кода с ideone отдаю)

Comment: @etki, смахивает на определение (definition я имею в виду, не detection, хотя второе тоже) runtime-типа массива?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ не столько на вопрос, сколько на разгоревшуюся дискуссию:

> If T is an array type TC[], that is, an array of components of type
>   TC, then a compile-time error occurs unless one of the following is
>   true:
>
> - TC and SC are the same primitive type.
> - TC and SC are reference types and type SC can undergo casting    conversion to TC.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1

Дальше нужно проговорить одну особенность ArrayList. Дело в том, что не зная реального типа (см. type erasure), ArrayList хранит в себе данные в виде `Object[]`. С некоторыми ухищрениями он мог бы хранить и `E[]`, но все равно до тех пор, пока он бы не был скомпилирован с реальным типом (насколько понимаю, вам бы в этом случае пришлось оперировать `StringList extends ArrayList<String>`, но могу ошибаться), `E[]` физически был бы `Object[]`. Массив, насколько мне известно, состоит из идентификатора типа, длины массива и непосредственно куском памяти для заполнения. В данном случае рантайм видит с левой и с правой стороны массивы, и получает их типы - `CharSequence` и `Object`, после чего убеждается, что `Object` не является `CharSequence` и выкидывает исключение - возвращай `ArrayList<String>` просто `String[]` под видом `Object[]`, проблемы бы не существовало, но он, к сожалению, так не может, пока тип не прокидывается ему прямо в конструктор.

Метод с `toArray(T[] targetTypeArray)` абсолютно верный в плане разрешения этой проблемы.

Простите, если что напутал.